# PhoneGap navigator.notification not working on Android

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I am developing an app with PhoneGap, the iOS version had no problems showing notifications but in Android I found the following error while attempting to show an alert box or a confirm box:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'exec' at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.2.0.js:984
```

Greatly appreciate if anyone know the solution, I'm stuck here.

Comment: please paste some code so we can understand that,

Comment: @AmitPrajapati Well, the problem happens when some functions needs to show a notification box, the code is something like this:         
    navigator.notification.alert("El documento ya está en sus descargas", function() {}, "Descargas");

Comment: do you have try to write navigator.notification.alert on device ready ??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you try to run this before PhoneGap is ready (so before **navigator.notification** object is initialized). Make sure your code is not executed before PhoneGap notify **deviceready** event. Just for test you can try to run a code like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function()
{
   navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
   navigator.notification.alert("Hello");
   navigator.notification.beep(1);   
}, false);
```

Comment: It is not working, I added a console.log to try to see better if this event is executed but it isn't working...